# google play game services SAVE GAME DATA Unity Example

Tags: google-play-games

Any one who using google play game services to save game state on cloud with unity game?
Is it feasible than using parse?
if game cache cleared than all state will got lost before sing in to google?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question related to parse, but I would recommend reading https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames .  Saved games are saved in the cloud, so they can be loaded from any device (like if someone plays the game on the phone, then later plays on a tablet).  It also works across platforms, so the saved game can be loaded from an android phone and ipad (for example).

Comment: Thanks for reply.
This really helful.
I have another question:
If I have to visit another user who is my facebook friend and also playing same game?It is possible?

Comment: Ask your second question separately -- you'll get a much better response.

Comment: The questions is not related to the answer and with the title is not connected. This just spend the title from other to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any service by which you can visit your friend game...which is a big for me...I am shift on parse..much much better.